# visual composer post grid custom query string for past events

Tags: wordpress, post, grid, visual-composer

i want to display the past events in home page. i am using visual composer post grid custom query option to compare with the current date and display posts less than current date.

```
post_type=event&posts_per_page=3&post_status=publish&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC&meta_key=date_short_order&meta_value=$today&compare=<&type=DATE
```

i have used this query but not working

Answer (score 2):

fetch the past event from current date

post type "event" and meta key name "date_short_order"

```
<?php
$today = date("Y/m/d h:i A");
$event_args=array(
    'type'                     => 'event',
    'post_status'              => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'           => 3,
    'meta_key'                 => 'date_short_order', //event_date
    'orderby'                  => 'meta_value_num', //or 'meta_value_num' , 'meta_value'
    'meta_query' => array(
                        array('key' => 'date_short_order',
                              'value' => $today, 
                              'compare' => '=<',
                              'type' => 'DATE',
                        )
                    ),
    'order'                    => 'DESC',
);
$event_my_query = null;
$event_my_query = new WP_Query($event_args);

if( $event_my_query->have_posts() ) 
{
     while ($event_my_query->have_posts()) : $event_my_query->the_post(); 
        the_title();
      endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query($event_my_query);
?>
```

[] is replaced by %5B%5D at URL encoding time.

'[' = %5B

']' = %5D

```
post_type=event&posts_per_page=3&post_status=publish&meta_key=date_short_order&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC&meta_query[0][key]=date_short_order&meta_query[0][value]=$today&meta_query[0][compare]=<&meta_query[0][type]=DATE
```

visual composer post grid custom query string for past events :

```
post_type=event&posts_per_page=3&post_status=publish&meta_key=date_short_order&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC&meta_query%5B0%5D%5Bkey%5D=date_short_order&meta_query%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=$today&meta_query%5B0%5D%5Bcompare%5D=<&meta_query%5B0%5D%5Btype%5D=DATE
```

Comment: Thank you. But i am using visual composer post grid custom query option this is not working with my case. i need query string like as i posted above.

Comment: post_type=event&posts_per_page=3&post_status=publish&meta_key=date_short_order&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC&meta_query[0][key]=date_short_order&meta_query[0][value]=$today&meta_query[0][compare]=<&meta_query[0][type]=DATE

Comment: try above query

Comment: I have used your query but it is showing the upcoming events also. I need to show only past events in that section.

Comment: I used your updated query but it is not showing any post now. is there any issue with my custom field date picker?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146499/discussion-between-ravi-kumar-and-shital-marakana).